# How can I atomically open or create a file and know which action occurred?

Tags: c#, .net

Given a file path, I wish to perform either of two actions atomically, and be able to determine which of the two actually occurred:

1. Open the file if it exists
2. Otherwise create a new file

The results of the operation should be:

1. An open file stream
2. An indication of what action occurred

So far, I've attempted to `System.IO.File.Open()` with `System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, but that method provides no mechanism to distinguish whether the file was opened or created.

Comment: I would start with a `FileInfo` object. Use the `Exists` property to initially determine its state, then use the `OpenWrite` method to open a stream to write to (ignoring your requirement for atomicity).

Comment: Before you call either just call File.Exists() and if it returns false then the file has been created once you call either.

Comment: It might help to explain why this needs to be atomic.

Comment: @Bauss: That's not an atomic operation. The file could have been created by another process in between the two calls.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Regarding the atomicity requirement, I'm trying to eliminate race conditions in my code, so I'm seeking atomicity merely for a clean design.  A secondary motivation is that my original implementation actually did use the `Exists` check on the `FileInfo` object, but for some weird reason, it was returning `false` even though I could see and open the file!  So I thought this route would be more reliable, if I could get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting my best-attempt solution so far in answer to my own question, but I hope a better solution will turn up, because mine doesn't solve the problem exactly.  The solution is atomic, but fails to strictly identify which action was taken for a particular corner case.

My solution is to treat any zero-byte file as equivalent to a newly-created file.  Of course, this is a false equivalence since it is perfectly possible to open an existing zero-byte file.

Nevertheless, for the purposes of my application (and many other applications) it is practical to treat the two as equivalent.  In my application, I either intend to open a file containing existing data, or else publish data to a new file.  From that perspective, if the data didn't exist, the file may as well not have existed.  However, the solution will be inadequate for applications which treat a zero-byte file as significant.

**EDIT** As @Martin Soles has noted, it may be possible for other processes to write to the file after it has been created.  To prevent this race condition, the file must be opened with `System.IO.FileShare.Read`.

Implementation:

```
public FileStream OpenOrCreateFile(string path, FileAccess fileAccess, out bool isNewFileForAllPracticalPurposes)
{
    var fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, fileAccess, FileShare.Read);
    isNewFileForAllPracticalPurposes = (fs.Length == 0); // Consider any zero-byte file to be a "new" file.
    return fs;
}
```

Usage:

```
bool isNewFileForAllPracticalPurposes;
OpenOrCreateFile(@"C:\myFile.txt", FileAccess.ReadWrite, out isNewFileForAllPracticalPurposes);

// Alert! This assignment lies, strictly speaking.
bool aNewFileWasCreated = isNewFileForAllPracticalPurposes;
```

Comment: Depending on what you are using for the file access, you may still run into an issue if another process created the file and was able to start writing to it between your check for a zero length file and the actual return statement. By that, you may want to open the file locked to prevent other processes from being able to write.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to get closer to the iron, you can use the Win32 CreateFile API to meet your atomicity requirement. Use OPEN_ALWAYS as the dwCreationDisposition value.  If you succeed in opening the file, you can call GetLastError to check for the ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS value to determine whether you created it or opened an existing file.  I know it may seem weird to call GetLastError after a successful operation, but that is a common Win32 idiom for ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.

Once you have the file handle, you can use the .Net SafeFileHandle class to wrap it and attach it to a FileStream.

But I fear this only pushes your synchronization problem a little further down the road.

Comment: It seems like this solution would work.  Could you clarify your last statement: "I fear this only pushes your synchronization problem a little further down the road"?  Is there a race condition I'm not seeing?

Comment: Without knowing more about what will be done with the file once multiple threads/processes have it open, it's hard to get specific.  But it comes down to how will you synchronize access to the file once it is in use?  This is made all the more interesting due to FileStream objects being buffered.